# G-WAN trouble when minifying Javascript

Tags: javascript, minify, g-wan

I'm testing this web server, but i got stuck with a little problem.

The thing is that when I use a library framework like **ExtJS 4.2.1**, in the *ext-all-dev.js* file there are some regexp that the compressor(It's **gzip**, right?) doesn't compress properly, for example, in the lines:

```
9906    history = [],
9907    slashDotSlashRe = /\/\.\//g,
9908    dotRe = /\./g,
```

the compressor does this:

```
3618    history=[],
3619    slashDotSlashRe=/\/\.\dotRe=/\./g,
```

Is it maybe a bug of **G-WAN**? Do you guys have any solution?

By the way, when I use **gzip** with **nginx**, it doesn't give me any problem.

Thanks for the help ^^.

Comment: the G-WAN community on stackoverflow is very small (34 followers) maybe there is a forum for G-WAN questions out there

Comment: You are right, I'll ask in the feedback section, I didn't found any main forum to this web server. Thanks for replying ^^

Comment: This Javascript minification bug has been fixed one year ago in G-WAN version v4.5.1, and , on the top of that, minifying can be enabled/disabled at startup, like many other by-default options in the v4.x gwan/init.c script file.

Comment: My current version of G-WAN is 4.3.14, so I'll upgrade it.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but the last public versión is the one I have, I cant download v4.5.1. http://gwan.com/timeline/2013.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a javascript minification error rather than gzip? In daemon mode (`gwan -d`), G-WAN minifies javascript and html on the fly, but this feature is known to be buggy in the latest public release. You probably can contact Pierre for a newer non-public version of G-WAN.

In the mean time, you can test your code by running G-WAN without `-d`.

Comment: That worked for me, witout the -d, at least i can test code now ^^ i'll contact with Pierre, thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can also download latest version on http://solicms.com/!page/en/post/show/201403281748-gwan-4-11-20

This version will allow you to don't minify JS files while running as daemon : check this page [GWAN is modifying jquery.min.js to error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468208/gwan-is-modifying-jquery-min-js-to-error/21469043#21469043)

Enjoy :)